# Native fetch request equivalent of Axios request using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, axios, fetch

I have this function:

```
const sendValidateJWTRequestFetch = (url: string, token: string) =>
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
  })
  .then(response =>
    response.ok ? response : Promise.reject<Response>(response)
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.Token)
```

It is working fine, but in prod enviroment I'm having some CORS issues, anyway, that's not the question, what I want to use `axios` now for this `get`. I'm trying this:

```
const sendValidateJWTRequest = (url: string, token: string) =>
  axios.get(url, {
    headers: {Authorization: token, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    crossDomain: true
  })
  .then(resp => resp.data ? resp : Promise.reject<Response>(resp))
  .then(response => response);
```

Not sure how to work with TS, Im getting this error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

EDIT: for getting the `crossDomain: true` working I had to add this in the code:

```
declare module 'axios' {
  export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
    crossDomain: boolean;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should set-up the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on server, rather than on the client to fix the CORS issues.

Comment: Yes, this questios has nothing to do with CORS, I want to know how to reproduce the same function above using fech but with axios

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with `Response` type - it's coming from fetch API and it's not matching what Axios is using. Basically those two libraries does not share typings. You need to use `AxiosResponse` instead.

The other difference you might want to be careful about is that Axios does not handle errors in the same way as FetchAPI. In Fetch you have `.ok` property and resolved promise, but in axios the promise would be rejected if status > 400 would be returned from server. So you don't need to reject the response yourself, but use `.catch` if you need to handle it differently.